# Responsive Design: Is there a way to automatically enlarge and reduce my website to the height instead of the width of the window?

Tags: html, css, mobile, browser, responsive

I have a website that has content. As an example it is 900px high and 1014px wide. On mobile phones etc. the size of the ad automatically adapts to the width of the screen and if there is an excess of height, the display simply scrolls. But I want it to adapt to the height instead of the width of the page/screen.

I want to do it this way because on most mobile devices my content is too long in height, which is a problem, and if it is a bit shorter in width, then it's not a problem because I would simply have space left and right.

Thanks in advance
Cyknos

Edith:
So here some Example Code (i'm not allowed to show the original Code):

HTML (Body):

```
<div class="content">
  //here are some images, other divs and much more 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 910px;
}
```

Two examples to descripe how it is now:

1. If the Window/Screen has a size of 1200px width and only 800px in height, the overflow-down is only with scroll visible -> thats normal.
2. If the Windoe/Screen has a size of 900px width and 1000px height it would "zoom out" my page, so the hole content is Visible -> thats also normal.

My Goal: 
My goal is, that if the height of the Window/Screen will become smaller as the height of the Content -> then the same thing should happen as normaly it does on example 2

Comment: Well you could always use vieport-units ( vh -> height , vw -> width ). But keep in mind that if for example you have an image. And you set it 100vh and want to keep the aspect ratio you will have overflow on X axis. What is this `ad` your are talking about ? An image ? An iframe ? Please share code that reproduces your current situation. Not just a ' story '

Comment: I believe media queries' doc will help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I have searched for a more "mathematical" solution. I postet my answer, how i solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution (Example-Code):

```
var result = [];
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
var contentHeight = 800; //your content
function bodySizing() {
    if(window.innerHeight < contentHeight) {
        var diff = contentHeight-window.innerHeight;
        var substractor = diff/contentHeight;
        var scale = 1-substractor;

        if(scale<1) { //only downsizing, no upsizing
            $('body').css('zoom', scale);
            $('body').css('-moz-transform', 'scale('+scale+')');
            $('body').css('-o-transform', 'scale('+scale+')');

            if(isFirefox) {
                $('body').css("background-size", result[0]*scale+"px " + result[1]*scale + "px");
            } else {
                $('body').css("background-size", result[0]+"px " + result[1] + "px");
            }   
        }    
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added FF-Fix